# How to find out what workspace a VM is connected to?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I checked one of my log analytics workspaces and it says that one of our VMs is connected to another workspace. I checked all the other workspaces and they all say the same thing. So how do I find out which workspace it's connected to?

Comment: Hi, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks. Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [azure powershell az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.5.0) to find out the workspace associated with the vm.

The powershell command is as below:

```
#get all the Log Analytics Workspace 
$all_workspace = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace

$myvm_name = "xxx"
$myvm_resourceGroup= "xxx"

#if it's a windows vm, use the extension_name below
$extension_name = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" 

$myvm = Get-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $myvm_resourceGroup -VMName $myvm_name -Name $extension_name

$workspace_id = ($myvm.PublicSettings | ConvertFrom-Json).workspaceId

#$workspace_id

foreach($w in $all_workspace)
{
if($w.CustomerId.Guid -eq $workspace_id)
  { 

  #here, print the vm and it's related log analytics workspace
  Write-Output "the vm: $($myvm_name) writes log to Log Analytics workspace named: $($w.name)"
  }
}
```

The test result:

[image]